# How Boost::uBLAS mapped_matrix works?

Tags: matrix, boost, sparse-matrix, ublas

There are lots of references about Boost::uBLAS compressed_matrix and coordinate_matrix. But I found no explanation about mapped_matrix. How is it implemented?

Which strategy of sparse storage does it use?

Plus: can someone provide me some reference in papers or books?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_sparse.html#mapped_matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Plus: can someone provide me some reference in papers or books?

There doesn't seem to be actual books for this library. The documentation is here

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_sparse.html#mapped_matrix

On quick scan it answers your questions:

[image]

> How is it implemented.

It's implemented as a container adapter. It only stores non-zero elements. These are stored in an associative container internally.

By default the underlying associative container is `std::map`, but it's customizable using the `A` template argument.

> Wich strategy of sparse storage it uses?

It only stores non-zero elements. These are stored in an associative container internally. See above.

Additionally, you can note the precise way in which the element indices are transformed into a key for the associative container (depending on `F`: row-major or column-major organization) and what guarantees this holds for weak total ordering of elements in a sparse matrix compared to the corresponding dense matrix models. (See above).

Comment: I know that documentation. It does not answer my question. There is no enough information about how it works. But thank you for your quick scan.

Comment: My quick scan only used about 3 sentences from the linked documentation and **all** the answers are there. I elaborated my answer to make that more explicit. Perhaps you can tell us what — specifically — information you are missing?

Comment: I could not explain myself before because my english is poor. But the information you provided is great. Thank you very much!